# How can I use the Create of the Turtlebot on the serial port?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a custom built Turtlebot with an iRobot Create. However I do not have a serial to USB adapter.

How can I use the serial cable of the Create for my Turtlebot? I already found out that in [turtlebot_node.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/fb8354a98ac5/turtlebot_node/nodes/turtlebot_node.py#l83) the port for the Create is set to ttyUSB0. What do I have to change here, so that I can use the serial port? Do I have to change anything else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40289/how-can-i-use-the-create-of-the-turtlebot-on-the-serial-port?/) by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set your serial port path in launch file:

```
<launch>
      <node pkg="turtlebot_node" type="turtlebot_node.py" name="turtlebot_node" output="screen" respawn="true" args="--respawnable">
        <param name="bonus" value="false" />
        <param name="update_rate" value="30.0" />
        <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyS0" />
        <param name="publish_tf" value="true" />
      </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1